# Is it possible to forwards imports when starting a process

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm generating python code using another python file, which I then execute using subprocess.

The issue is that the generated code include quite a few imports which makes it slow. I often work in ipython cells (which have memory), so the generation imports are retained. But, the imports of the generated files are reran everytime, because the new subprocess does not retain the imports.

Hence, I was wondering if there is a way to supply your subprocess with imports. This way the imports can be loaden once in my generation script and forwarded to the generated code. I did a little google and couldn't find much on the matter, so any input would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: To add some context. The reason I generate python code is because I automatically create classes from input. These classes are required for a the underlying model. Using `exec` might be possible, but would probably be relatively difficult to implement, plus I like having the ability to run the generated file on its own.

Comment: How are you running the new process? What objects do you use?

Comment: First question: ***why*** are you dynamically creating python code? Why can't it just be normal code, just parametrized to fit your changing needs?

Comment: Bear in mind that `subprocess` is designed to run arbitrary processes, which may not be Python-related at all. Its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) doesn't appear to have any hooks that favor running Python scripts in particular.

Comment: Rather than using `subprocess` to start a new process, you might try forking the existing process instead. (That might involved using `exec` to generate the code instead of simply writing code to a file.)

Comment: You can create classes on the fly without creating literal Python code, e.g. using [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type).

Comment: Yes, @deceze that is very True. Using type was my first approach, but I ran into problems when using type generated objects in combination with multiprocessing modules and decorators.

Comment: @IanMullens You might want to ask a question about *that*.

Comment: Yes very True, but I have actually already been down that rabbit hole once. I have actually found a method to run my scripts now. I use multiple cores for large simulations and the imports are no real issue there. Then for small simulations I use a single process and I will be able to use the exec/type method without issue to reduce execution time.